# LDAP Can't perform an authenticated bind - Windows Server 2008 R2 Using PHP/Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, php, active-directory, ldap

I'm having issues performing an authenticated bind against the server. The issues doesn't appear to be in code however maybe a server issue.

Just so you know;

- LDAP is enabled in Apache/PHP
- I'm connecting as user@domain.com
- The domain controller has LDAP running and an entry in the firewall (Windows Server 2008 R2) The issue might be here, this was setup as a DC and is running LDAP by default. I did no special configuration on LDAP
- I can perform an anonymous bind but not an authenticated one

I can bind anonymously using this script;

```
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("machinename.domain.com")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding anonymously
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn);

    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind anonymous successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind anonymous failed...";
    }

}
```

However when I try to do an authenticated bind using this script, it fails.

```
// Authenticated Bind
$ldaprdn  = 'username@domain.com';     // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = 'password';  // associated password

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("machinename.domain.com")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: "username@domain.com" is neither an RDN or DN, it could be a user's UPN though.  Try it without the "@domain.com" or get the full DN of the object, something like "CN=username,OU=something,DC=example,DC=com". It also may help if you updated your question to detail which error message your seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I've found a solution and I'll post it up shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after much investigation I have turned on error info using `ldap_errno()` and `ldap_error()` and found it bringing back the error 'Strong(er) authentication required' have discovered two possible solutions;

**Adjust Group Policy Settings**

- Negotiate Signing (Network security: LDAP client signing requirements)
- No signing requirements (Domain Controller: LDAP server signing requirements)
- Result: Managed to bind successfully and when I enter the username or password incorrectly and it throws an 'Invalid credentials' as expected.

**Enable LDAP over SSL (LDAPS)**

- http://www.christowles.com/2010/11/enable-ldap-over-ssl-ldaps-on-windows.html
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321051